# How is/can documentation be added for new tag?

Tags: support, documentation

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched and did not find one.

Having seen the documentation sections of a few of my favorites:

[F#](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/f%23/topics?tab=requests)
[TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/topics)
[Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/prolog/topics)

and voting for them for

[Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic)
[AST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-syntax-tree)
[Compiler-Construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction)

I wanted to add something to the [WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) tag but saw no documentation. I then realized I did not have enough points to cast a vote so decided to see if others [could](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wsl/topusers). That's when I realized that, if I understand how documentation works, the WSL tag will not be getting documentation for a while because only a few months ago it was developer preview, and on 8/2/2016 became generally available but as [beta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).

How does a new tag get documentation if there are not enough people with the privilege to vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tag simply isn't eligible. See the help center about [Adding Documentation To Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-add-tags):

> In order for a tag to have documentation, it must have at least 500 questions and 10 committed users.

That tag currently only has 44 questions. Past that, you only need at least 10 users with at least 150 reputation and one positively scored answer in the tag, which would be pretty odd if that didn't happen by the time it reached 500 questions.

Comment: Nice to know the details. Didn't know about the 500 questions requirement.

Comment: Yet another good reason to decouple docs from Q&A just a little bit.